# Testing closed over functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

I currently have two functions each with test:

```
function A(x) {
  // do A things
  return Aresults;
}
function testA() {
  // this put A through its test and make sure it does what it's supposed to
}
```

and

```
function B(x) {
  // do B things which involve using A
  return Bresults;
}
function testB() {
  // this put B through its test and make sure it does what it's supposed to
}
```

I now realize that the only use of A is in B. so I want to re-factor to isolate and protect code into:

```
function B(x) {
  function A(x) {
    // do A things
    return Aresults;
  }
  // do B things which involve using A
  return Bresults;
}
function testB() {
  // this put B through its test and make sure it does what it's supposed to
}
```

My question is how could I add tests for A now that it's a closed over function of B? i.e. where does my testA function go?

Comment: looks similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932917)

Comment: and to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569647) Why couldn't I find this before I asked?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. The aim of unit testing is to test *behaviour* not *implementation*.

So you test what method does, not how it does it.

From this perspective you should only care of side effects produced by a function call, that's it.